# pdftk utility and batch file

Tags: pdf, batch

I cant for the life of me figure out what I'm missing.  I have the following batch file:

When I run this batch file from my desk against a mapped drive it runs just fine

```
FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") DO pdftk "%%G\*.pdf" cat output "%%G\Report.pdf"
```

When I run the same exact batch file on the server itself, the place where the mapped drive is located on, it doesnt run and makes me think I have a syntax problem

I just don't understand whats going on, and my eyes are having a hard time keeping track of what might be different.  The server where it isn't working is windows 2003, my desktop where the same batch file is working is Windows 7.

Comment: please don't add `[belongs-on-X]` tags.

Comment: @duhaas: the screenshots are informative, but since they're all text it'd be much more legible if you used the markup code formatting (indent 4 spaces) (or use the HTML `<pre></pre>` tags).

Comment: @duhaas: the "please don't add `[belongs-on-X]` tags" was directed at others editing the tags on this question; it was not directed at you.  (sorry for the confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") DO pdftk "%%G\*.pdf" cat output "%%G\Report.pdf"
```

Try this

```
FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") DO pdftk %%G\*.pdf cat output "%%G\Report.pdf"
```

The quotations around `"%%G\*.pdf"` I believe made the * look like a letter to the batch command and not a wildcard qualifier.

sorry if this is old but I just found it and used it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like you can do wildcard expansion in the set part of your command, the `("*")`, but the command parameters `"%%G\*.pdf"` are not getting expanded.  Why it's behaving inconsistently from one machine to the other, I'm not sure.

Since you only want to process pdf docs, move the wildcard * make you command like:

```
FOR /D /r %%G in ("*.pdf") DO pdftk "%%G" cat output "%%G\Report.pdf"
```

Comment: in the last paragraph he says the server's Win2k3, desktop is Win7.  i expect the full explanation has to to do with Win2k3's command shell.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion dave, doesnt appear that helps as then it no longers cycles through the actual folders when i do that, it basically does nothing.

Comment: @~quack.  You may be right.  duhas' original syntax & mine works on XP, vista & win7.  Another culprit is the FOR command itself on Win2k3.  Can't find a documented smoking gun, however, & I don't have a copy of that OS to play with.

Comment: well, i'm assuming the FOR command is a shell-builtin command instead of a separate executable, but whichever, we're talking about the same thing.  i'd help test but i don't have w2k3 either.  :-/